# PHP Regex Match Whitespace

Tags: php, regex

I am having trouble matching the space after `content="Wordpress` in the following regex

```
$metatag = '<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.8.2">';
$metaregex = '/<meta.*?content="Wordpress.(?<version>.*?)"/';

preg_match($metaregex, $metatag, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a typo mistake. Instead of:

```
$metaregex = '/<meta.*?content="Wordpress.(?<version>.*?)"/';
```

It should be:

```
$metaregex = '/<meta.*?content="WordPress.(?<version>.*?)"/';
```

Notice Word**p**ress vs Word**P**ress.

---

Or you can ignore case by using the `i` modifier:

```
$metaregex = '/<meta.*?content="wordpress.(?<version>.*?)"/i';
```

- `i` **modifier**: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of
  [a-zA-Z])

Answer (score 2):

A better approach to this would be using a parser and then use a regex on just the attributes value.

```
$html = '<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.8.2">';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$heads = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');
foreach ($heads as $head) {
    if($head->getAttribute('name') == 'generator' && preg_match('/wordpress (?<version>(?:\d+\.?)+)/i', $head->getAttribute('content'), $version)) {
        die($version['version']);
    }
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/YlsFP